# Which SDFormat corresponds to version of Gazebo

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've searched around and its not clear which version of the SDF spec (1.4-1.6) corresponds to Gazebo7, etc. My Ubuntu 16.04 package manager says I have SDFormat4 install, further confusing me. Why isn't the binary release matching the spec version?

From the Gazebo changelog, it seems Gazebo7 uses 1.6, but its not 100% clear. Perhaps this can be added to the documentation/website somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15456/which-sdformat-corresponds-to-version-of-gazebo/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-02-16**:
This is a common source of confusion, see this question for example: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12544/sdf-versions-unable-to-convert-from-sdf-version-15-to-14/

**Comment by [hugomatic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/59/hugomatic/) on 2017-02-17**:
Gazebo7 should support SDF 1.6 but I cannot find a clear answer by simply looking at dpkg, changelogs or sdformat.org

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2017-02-20**:
How can we improve this for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The SDF spec version supported has nothing to do with the versioning of SDFormat package.  `SDF` is a format specification and as such, it has it's own versions: 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 (as of today). In debian/ubuntu it is distributed with the package name of `sdformat-sdf` and it is not strictly related to a particular version of the rest of `SDFormat` packages although all them come from the same source tarball.

`SDFormat` is a C++ software which works with the SDF specification. It follows semantic versioning and major versions corresspond to changes in ABI. It versioning scheme has nothing to do with the `SDF` protocol supported.

The confusion could come from the fact that both are hosted in the same repository and are installed together. In `Gazebo` we use the dependency directly on `SDFormat` since it would bring the `SDF` protocol needed by a particular version (plus the  expected API, etc).

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2017-02-22**:
On http://sdformat.org/ there should be a table comparing Gazebo version to SDFormat verison like there is on gazebosim.org.  Maybe a link to more details (the ones you just provided here). Where can I open a ticket for this documentation request?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-02-22**:
I started something like this on this pull request to gazebo tutorials: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-requests/386/split-step-to-install-dependencies-from/diff @jose-luis-rivero, what do you think of adding information about the SDF spec there too? Feel free to commit directly to that branch if you wish.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2017-02-22**:
I've added some information to that PR: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/commits/f53ab05209d7df1668116533800e8c0042f715cf?at=default , hopefully it will help with the problem. We could also consider to add the information about SDF vs SDFormat in the sdformat.org front page.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-02-22**:
Thank you!